# How to call C++ function from external file?

Tags: c++, c, header-files

i have 3 C++ source files and i need to call a function from one file into another

`getch.cpp`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "getch2.h"
main()
{
 char ch='x';
 fun(ch);   
}
```

`getch2.cpp`

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(char);
main()
{

}
void fun(char x)
{
printf("the ascii value of the char is %d",x);
}
```

`func.h`

```
void fun(char);
```

when i compile getch2.cpp i get the error

C:\Users\amolsi\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1k7Vdp.o   getch.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `fun(char)'

C:\Users\amolsi\Documents\C files\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your `main` functions need to be changed to:

   ```
   int main() { ... }
   ```
2. Both `getch.cpp` and `getch2.cpp` contain `main` functions. You cannot use them together to form an executable. They'll have to be used to create separate executables.
3. In order for you to use `fun` from `getch.cpp` and `getch2.cpp` to build executables, you need to move the definition of `void fun(char){...}` from `getch2.cpp` to another `.cpp` file. Let's call it `func.cpp`.
4. Use `getch.cpp` and `func.cpp` to build one executable.
5. Use `getch2.cpp` and `func.cpp` to build the other executable.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

File `func.h`:

---

```
void fun(char);
```

---

File `func.cpp`:

---

```
void fun(char x)
{
   printf("the ascii value of the char is %d",x);
}
```

---

File `getch.cpp`:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h"

int main()
{
   char ch='x';
   fun(ch);
   return 0;
}
```

---

File `getch2.cpp`:

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "func.h"

int main()
{
   char ch='y';
   fun(ch);
   return 0;
}
```

---

Use `getch.cpp` and `func.cpp` to build executable `getch.exe`.
Use `getch2.cpp` and `func.cpp` to build executable `getch2.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#include` is fine, the problem is that you don't implement `fun` anywhere.

Comment: The error you get is when you compile `getch.cpp`, not `getch2.cpp` (which has `fun`).